# How can I send this customized query with graphql in flutter?

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, graphql

Here is the query which I tried

```
static String mainQuery = """query { user(id: "your_id") { id name income transactions { id title type currency created_at userId }}}""";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `GraphQL` package in `Flutter`, you can send queries with `GraphQLClient.mutate or GraphQLClient.query` methods for this issue. You can send a customized query in `GraphQL` like that in `Flutter` :

```
query user(\$id: String){
  user(id: \$id) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```